# Button Onclick function executes on load

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

When the page loads, the function executes whether the button was clicked or not, note that i am using EJS.

I Tried Changing the `<%` tag to `<%=` and `<%-`, as well as making it an arrow function: `<% () => Delt(this.id);%>`.

```
<%function Delt() { Array.pop(); }%>
<button onclick="<%Delt(this.id);%>">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused here with client side and server side ,whatever lies in `ejs` tags gets executed on server before your dom loads.So the function defined in `ejs` tags are executed ,coz they are not in client side `js`.Try defining your function in client side js and not in ejs ,same for function calling.

```
<%function Delt() { Array.pop(); }%> // function definition in ejs
<button onclick="<%Delt(this.id);%>">Delete</button> // function call in ejs
```

> So all the stuff gets executed in server before your dom loads,you are just making normal function call in ejs ,it doesn't sees your onclick coz that's your browser's part.

Comment: Thanks for the help, im going to attempt using socket.io to get the desired effect.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you .Happy to help :)@IronInstrumentals